# Получаю ошибку при выполнении mysqldupm как решить?

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, резервное-копирование

Я выполняю команду:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD crm > test.sql
```

и получаю ошибку mysqldump:

```
Got error: 1449: "The user specified as a definer ('crm'@'%') does not exist" when using LOCK TABLES
```

используемый user - admin

Прописывал после его создания `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%';` и `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Что не так?

Comment: Справку надо читать внимательно. `mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD --databases crm > test.sql`

Comment: Боюсь ошибка всё ещё не исчезла :С
Прописал точь в точь как тут, но всё равно дропает ошибку

Comment: А нет, данная ошибка исчезла.. теперь появилась новая) mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае с mysql 8.0 я смог сделать mysqldump -u root -p --databases crm > crm.sql
В случае с mysql 5.7 была ошибка что user вроде как не может быть дефаулт для большей инфы на этот счёт напишите mysqldump --help (там написаны поддерживаемые опции как я прочитал). В 5.7 я использовал mysqldump -u созданныйМнойПользователь -pPassword crm > crm.sql

Comment: в случае с 8.0 пароль соответственно не вводим

Comment: Вдруг кому надо, то вот стандартная структура экспорта с помощью mysqldump:
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD --databases DATABASE > myFile.sql;     
Импорт:        
mysqldump -u USER -pPassword --databases DATABASE < myFile.sql;     
Примечание: -pPassword - не ошибка, они пишутся слитно